How to Export All Region Data from an Oracle APEX Page into a Single CSV or PDF report?
I want to export all the displayed data from the screen consisting of different region types (e.g., Forms, Classic Reports, Interactive Reports, Tabs, etc.) into a single CSV or PDF report. What is the best way to achieve this?

Take a screenshot and save it to a PDF. Just kidding, but - not entirely. I don't think that there's any common and/or universal way of doing that. Apex offers export for reports, but for other regions you'd have to do it yourself. For example, pick a reporting tool you're good at and create custom reports for all those regions.

Also, with only one screen active at a time, I'm not sure how you would export content from other screens. Sounds like you would need to build a new report that captures all of your data at once for export, rather than capture multiple regions that weren't designed for export on multiple pages that can't really be accessed at the time time into  single export.
